# nlm function in R stats library gives different results across different R versions and different OS (windows, mac, linux)

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am using non-linear logistic regression (4pl/5pl) to fit the immunoassay data. 
R stats library offers a function nlm which is used for regression fit. 
We observed that nlm results specifically estimate values i.e. **bottom**, **top**, **ec50**, **slope**, **asym** values are different across various R versions and OS (window, mac, linux). **Is it expected/ acceptable?** 
In our attempt to debug this, we played around with one of the arguments in nlm function i.e. **ndigit**. ndigit's default value is **12**, but we set ndigit's value to a smaller number e.g. 4. 
After setting ndigit to a smaller number nlm results were same across diff R versions and OS. But now we observed that number of iterations in nlm log prints reduced significantly. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following post and update the question appropriately:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you compared the .Machine precision of these different systems?